# How to remove @{} characters from output in powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting

I just would like some help removing the `@{}` characters from my output
My script is to get the folder sizes from a specific Drive or Directory
Here is my script

```
$HugeFileSizeFolder= @() -join ','
$folder = "E:\New Folder\"
Get-ChildItem -Recurse $folder | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } | 
ForEach-Object { 
    $obj = New-Object PSObject  
    $Size = [Math]::Round((Get-ChildItem -Recurse $_.FullName | Measure-Object Length -Sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).sum / 1000MB, 2) 
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name  "Path" $_.FullName 
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name  "SizeGB" $Size        
    if ($Size -ge   2)
    {
        $HugeFileSizeFolder +=$obj
    }
}
$HugeFileSizeFolder | Out-string
$HugeFileSizeFolderFound = [boolean] $HugeFileSizeFolder
```

Here is a sample output
`@{Path=E:\New Folder\Folder1; SizeGB=3.4GB}`
I've tried the suggested tweaks but somehow I cannot get it to work ok maybe I'm not doing it right.

Your input and suggestions are very much appreciated

thanks
Newbie

Comment: What output format _are_ you aiming for? You might be able to solve this by simply removing `| Out-String`.

Comment: Hi Mathias, I'm creating an Automation Policy using Solarwinds NCentral. that's why I need the Out-string command

Answer (score 1):

> `$HugeFileSizeFolder = @() -join ','`

This makes `$HugeFileSizeFolder` contain a *string* (the empty string), not an empty *array*, as is your intent - the array you're later trying to append to with `+=`.

Because `$HugeFileSizeFolder` is a *string*, `+=` performs *string concatenation*, which results in representations such as `@{Path=E:\New Folder\Folder1; SizeGB=3.4GB}`<sup>[1]</sup>

While `$HugeFileSizeFolder = @()` *would* give you an empty array, it is better to avoid extending arrays *iteratively* with `+=`, because doing so requires creating a *new* array behind the scenes in every iteration - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/45375).

The more efficient - and simpler - alternative is to use the pipeline as an *assignment* statement that automatically collects all outputs for you:

```sh
$folder = "E:\New Folder"

$HugeFileSizeFolder = 
  Get-ChildItem -Recurse $folder | 
    Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } |
      ForEach-Object { 
        $obj = New-Object PSObject  
        $Size = [Math]::Round((Get-ChildItem -Recurse $_.FullName | Measure-Object Length -Sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).sum / 1000MB, 2) 
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name  "Path" $_.FullName 
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name  "SizeGB" $Size        
        if ($Size -ge 2) {
          # Output the object; all output objects are collected
          # in $HugeFileSizeFolder
          $obj 
        }
      }
    }

# Output the result (no need for Out-String)
$HugeFileSizeFolder

$HugeFileSizeFolderFound = [boolean] $HugeFileSizeFolder
```

---

As an aside: Since v3, PowerShell offers a fairly concise and efficient *literal* notation for creating `[pscustomobject]`s, so your `New-Object` and `Add-Member`-based object construction could be simplified to:

```
$obj = [pscustomobject] @{
  Path = $_.FullName
  SizeGB = [Math]::Round((Get-ChildItem -Recurse $_.FullName | Measure-Object Length -Sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Sum / 1000MB, 2)
}
```

---

<sup>[1] A simple demonstration: `'!' + [pscustomobject] @{ foo = 'bar' }` yields `'!@{foo=bar}'`</sup>

Comment: thanks mklemento.  Im passing this script to an Autmation Policy in Solarwinds NCentral that's why i need the out-string at the end. the error now im getting after removing the array is that the result is just saying System.Object[]

Comment: @RitcheFalle, that implies that Solarwinds NCentral  simply calls `.ToString()` on the `$HugeFileSizeFolder` array. If you use `Out-String` again, you'll get a _for-display_ representation, as you would see in the console, and that isn't suitable for _programmatic_ processing. So the question is: what is the right output format expected by Solarwinds NCentral? Can you send JSON, for instance? If so, use `$HugeFileSizeFolder | ConvertToJson`